# Cross Tab Browser Caching, Forcing Refresh

Tags: http, caching, http-headers, browser-cache

I have a JSON resource, let's call it /game/1, which is being publicly cached with a long duration. Based on some client-side logic, I want to occasionally want to refresh this resource (for instance, when I know something should be happening server-side - a game ending, in my case).

Once refreshed, I would like all downstream caches to update with the new content, so any requests to /game/1 will fetch the refreshed content. Appending a querystring with a random parameter won't work in this case.

I have tried adding the following headers **on the request**, which seems to work in a temperamental fashion in browsers other than IE:

```
    headers['Cache-Control'] = 'max-age=0, no-cache';
    headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';
```

Using these headers, Chrome seems to *sometimes* refresh the content, presumably based on some internal heuristics.

Does anyone have any better ideeas for what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting meta http-equiv="expires" content to zero.

Setting the 'expires' metatag to zero should force the browser to reload everything on each page visit. Forcing constant cache deletion will obviously slow down page loading (if all browsers obey it!) but maybe that's an acceptable trade-off. This won't help with downstream caches however, so it's far from a complete solution.

Comment: Disabling caching clearly fixes the bugs, but this question is about how to get the correct behaviour **with** optimal caching. Still not something I've found a solution for :)